# Is a GitHub account required for cloning a repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm putting together some documentation and don't have access to a non-configured machine to test this myself

I'm curious if you need a GitHub account to clone a repository from GitHub to a local machine.

Comment: In the question title you ask "Can you clone a Github repository without an account?" but in the question you say "I'm curious if you need a Github account to clone a repository from Github to a local machine."

These are logical opposites, which makes reading the answers confusing because the "No" answers seem reversed based on the title. @Stevoisiak Can you please fix it to make responses logically consistent? Maybe update the answers to be consistent based on which way you go with the title/text?

Comment: @rjurney I‘m not the question author, I simply made minor formatting edits.

Comment: @Stevoisiak I get that. He's long gone. Can you fix up the question? I don't have access on Super User to do it and it is needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No. You just use a different URL:

```
git clone https://github.com/SomeUser/SomeRepo.git
```

However, the local repo will be "read-only" in the sense that you won't be able to push your changes back to the original repo. You will still able to modify files and commit changes locally, though.

In contrast,

```
git clone git@github.com:UserName/OtherRepo.git
```

works only if you have properly set up your environment with the necessary SSH keys and whatnot, but in return you'll get a repository that permits you to commit/push the changes back to the remote repo.

(Sorry for the unintentional ad for GitHub, I just had it in mind.)

Edit: The original answer had the *git* protocol instead of *https* but [GitHub has since then turned it off](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the clarification.  I'm aware of the limitations by approaching a clone this way, but it's fine for the context of the process I'm documenting.

Comment: @JosephMainwaring I'm glad to have helped. Please don't forget to accept my answer when you'll be able to do so.

Comment: For GitLab it's `git clone https://gitlab.com/SomeUser/SomeRepo.git`

Comment: So in fact the answer isn't no. It is yes, but only read only via the http method. You should change the answer to indicate this. "No" sounds like you can't git clone Github repos without having a user and logging in.

Comment: Wait: I'm wrong. Sorry. The question is actually what is confusing. I commented there to make the required edits, I don't have the privileges here to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I was following some documentation for a product which required cloning from github. I didn't want to bother setting up an account so I needed to do exactly what was asked here.

The command in the documentation was:

```
git clone git://github.com/fcrepo4/fcrepo-message-consumer.git
```

but that just fails for me with.

```
Cloning into 'fcrepo-message-consumer'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tried

```
git clone git://github.com/fcrepo4/fcrepo-message-consumer.git
```

as suggested in one of the answers but that failed too with.

```
Cloning into 'fcrepo-message-consumer'...
fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

What finally worked was this:

```
git clone https://github.com/fcrepo4/fcrepo-message-consumer.git
```

Answer (score 5):

Or just use http prefix , and .git suffix is not mandatory too :

You can check with

```
git clone http://github.com/tizenteam/iotivity-example
```

Related info:

https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password/

Comment: Anonymous download actually wouldn't work for me until I removed the `.git` suffix.

Comment: Removing `.git` also works with the standard https clone url

Answer (score 1):

You could use Github Tokens https://github.com/settings/tokens and use this:

```
git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

(replace `${GITHUB_TOKEN}` with the actual token

Comment: this only works if you already have a github account.